A tool to facilitate convertion of Perl code into Python - at least as a workable draft
There is a collection of Perl scripts, mostly relatively simple ones, used for infrastructure management. However, maintaining them seems challenging as Perl usage is declining. We'd like to refactor these into a more maintainable language like Python. Are there any libraries or tools facilitate this process?
The proper one to consider would be a tool to produce readable Python source code that can then be manually refined and adjusted.
